# Where do you find new linux applications & tools

Tags: linux

I find myself finding new apps that are really useful and that I had no idea existed.

Where do you find out about new, more under the radar linux applications & tools?

What blogs are you following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow http://planet.ubuntu.com/ - lots of posts just about ubuntu, but quite often people talk about new apps they are developing or using. I skim it in google reader generally. Lots of other big open source projects have planets, including GNOME, KDE, Debian, Fedora, Mozilla ... If you choose the one that corresponds with you, you'll often read about gems of apps.

And if you use the terminal much, then I'll just recommend you try out [terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/):

[image: Terminator screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about anyone else but I periodically stumble around source forge for new projects popping up under categories in which I'm interested.  I don't follow any blogs, but I've come across some pretty amazing little projects on there.  Also, if you're interested in development create an account there and look for projects to which you'd like to contribute. :D

[www.sourceforge.net](http://www.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 1):

http://kde-apps.org/ has a lot of applications, specifically on KDE platform.

Comment: And http://www.gnomefiles.org/ for GNOME applications

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/linux-applications/
http://www.linux.com/
http://www.linux.org/apps/AppId_6015.html
http://linuxappfinder.com/package/citadel

All RSS feeds are added to my google reader, so i can easily search anything i want

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Ubuntu, you can use the add programs tool.  I've randomly read through the list before, and found some useful tools there!  I've also looked around sourceforge.net as well.

Both are great places to find new and interesting software.